# Выборка всех данных из MySQL с помощью SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Как с помощью SQLAlchemy написать запрос "SELECT * FROM table"?

Comment: А в чем проблема? Вы уже смотрели [примеры использования `.fetchall()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html)?

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas позволяет удобно выгрузить данные [из SQL](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) в  [Excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
pd.read_sql('select * from tab where ...', engine) \
  .to_excel(r'/path/to/excel_file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо. У меня вышел такой код:

```
import sqlalchemy as sql
eng = sql.create_engine('mysql://root:1234@localhost/test?charset=utf8')
res = eng.execute('SELECT * FROM table')
rows = res.fetchall()
```

Comment: Если вы всё равно пишете сырой sql, то зачем вам вообще sqlalchemy?

Comment: этот код сделан с нарушением идеологии ORM

Comment: Встала задача выгружать данные с mysql в xls файл. Из тех либ, что позволяют это делать, я решил остановится на pyexcel. Так как pyexcel может формировать файлы из данных, полученных с помощью sqlalchemy, то решил попробовать так и сделать, не вникая в суть ORM.